# Arduino Ethernet BOARD and PHP or HTML (RC car)

Tags: php, hyperlink, arduino, project, rc

I am all new to arduino, never used it before, and i need to use it for a project at school.
The project consists of building an RC car, a PHP webpage, and controlling the RC car with this php webpage. The layout of the webpage is made, and so is the car, also working if we open the ports. The question is how do i open the port through my php wepage? is this even possible, thanks !

I'm using Arduino ethernet board (not shield)

Comment: What do you mean by "open ports through php"? Is the arduino getting commands through a socket, or by opening a page? Please provide a bit more details

Answer (score 1):

The basic concept is that the Arduino is a web page server.  You will need code on the Arduino that implements a TCP/IP stack.  Usually this code is supplied by the manufacturer of the Ethernet board for the Arduino.

Usually, the web page will send an HTTP "GET" command to the web server, which is a specific IP address and port number.  The Arduino server needs to "listen" at that IP-port addr, this code is part of the TCP/IP stack.

To answer your specific question, on your Web page browser, enter:

```
   http:\\host_ip_addr:80
```

Where 80 is usually the HTTP port number, but your arduino can listen on any port, so a valid entry might be:

```
   http:\\lclhost:8000
```

Hope this gets you started in the right direction.